# Discarding certain related rows in a query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a wide table, but only 5 columns are relevant for the problem. Let's say the table is like this:

```
Bsns_ID | Vch_ID | Vch_Line | Pay_Status | Pay_ID | Bank | Amnt
COM04   | 00001  |        1 | Received   | 000001 | BK01 | 2970
COM04   | 00001  |        1 | Pending    | NULL   | NULL |   30
COM01   | 00352  |        1 | Received   | 000832 | BK98 | 3000
COM01   | 00352  |        2 | Received   | 000967 | BK98 | 6784
COM01   | 00352  |        2 | Received   | 000834 | BK98 | 6784
COM33   | 00023  |        1 | Received   | 000076 | BK43 | 4950
COM33   | 00023  |        1 | Pending    | NULL   | NULL |   50
COM02   | 00065  |        1 | Pending    | 000804 | BK45 | 9946
```

`Bsns_ID`, `Vch_ID`, `Vch_Line` are my compound key that identify a specific item, but an item can have multiple payments, so the full ID for a specific row includes the `Pay_ID` column.

What I need is to sum the amount of any row that satifies `Pay_Status = 'Pending'` and `Pay_ID = NULL` with the amount in its related rows with same `Bsns_ID`, `Vch_ID`, `Vch_Line`, and discard the row in question. The result of the sum must replace the `Amnt` value of the related row. A sample result would be like so:

```
Bsns_ID | Vch_ID | Vch_Line | Pay_Status | Pay_ID | Bank | Amnt
COM04   | 00001  |        1 | Received   | 000001 | BK01 | 3000 --(2970 + 30)
COM01   | 00352  |        1 | Received   | 000832 | BK98 | 3000
COM01   | 00352  |        2 | Received   | 000967 | BK98 | 6784
COM01   | 00352  |        2 | Received   | 000834 | BK98 | 6784
COM33   | 00023  |        1 | Received   | 000076 | BK43 | 5000 --(4950 + 50)
COM02   | 00065  |        1 | Pending    | 000804 | BK45 | 9946
```

With the following rows not present:

```
COM04   | 00001  |        1 | Pending    | NULL   | NULL |   30
COM33   | 00023  |        1 | Pending    | NULL   | NULL |   50
```

**Edit:** I'm working in [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/).

Comment: Your example data has the removed rows only in cases where there is exactly one other row.  What happens when there are multiple other rows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: There are no multiple 'other rows' for the same item, at least not in cases where the mentioned conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

```
with pendings as (
    select Bsns_ID
        ,Vch_ID
        ,Vch_Line
        ,sum(Amnt) as s_Amnt
    from TABLE_NAME
    where pay_id is null
    group by 1,2,3
)
sekect a.Bsns_ID
    ,a.Vch_ID
    ,a.Vch_Line
    ,a.Pay_status
    ,a.Pay_ID
    ,a.Bank
    ,a.Amnt + coalesce(p.Amnt,0) as Amnt
from TABLE_NAME as a
left join pendings as p on a.bsns_id = p.bsns_id and a.vch_id = p.vch_id and a.Vch_Line = p.Vch_Line;
```

But like @GordonLinoff implies if `COM01   | 00352  |        2` was to have a third line with a 'pending' it will match two lines.. the gap is you imply `pay_id` should be used as the forth unique key, but then ask to have all null `pay_id` keys added to all non-null rows which seems dangerous.